# NSPasteboard: Dragging multiple objects of different types

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, nstableview, export-to-excel, nspasteboard

I want to copy data from my app into a Numbers or Excel sheet. The data consists mostly of integers, but also some images. I try to accomplish this by first putting the data in a NSTableView, and then writing the data to the pasteboard via the method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard
{
    NSArray * dataToPaste = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t",
                                               data1,
                                               data2,
                                               data3,
                                               data4,
                                               data5,
                                               data6,
                                               data7,
                                               data8],
                                               [An NSImage], nil];
    [pboard writeObjects:dataToPaste];
    return YES;
}
```

If I don't add the NSImage at the end, all data is copied nicely, but as soon as I add the NSImage to the array, only the image gets copied, and if I add two NSImages, only the first gets copied. What have I missed?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Btw, I just realized that not even Numbers.app manages to drag copy cells with both text and images to neither Excel nor TextEdit. Between Numbers files works however.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray * dataToPaste = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %ld \t %@",
                                               data1,
                                               data2,
                                               data3,
                                               data4,
                                               data5,
                                               data6,
                                               data7,
                                               data8],
                                               [An NSImage], nil];
    [pboard writeObjects:dataToPaste];

Use "%@" format specifier like for image, %ld for NSnumber, May be it will be the Solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, using %@ for the image only generates metadata of the image: <NSImage 0x10060f1d0 Size={619, 100} Reps=(
    "NSBitmapImageRep 0x10066ac90 Size={619, 100} ColorSpace=Color LCD colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=619x100 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=<NSMutableData: 0x1006097f0>"
)>